# Redirect / Rewrite https to http except one page

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect `https` to `http` except one page.

**What I need:**

```
https://abc.subdomain.com/testing1
https://abc.subdomain.com/testing2
https://abc.subdomain.com/resultant
```

to

```
 http://abc.subdomain.com/testing1
 http://abc.subdomain.com/testing2
 https://abc.subdomain.com/resultant
```

when `resultant` page hit with `https` it remains on `https`

**What I have tried so far:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/resultant
RewriteRule ^/resultant https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but it is not redirecting all other pages to `http`

**MY HTACCESS CODE**

```
#AuthType Basic
#AuthName "sentineldev DEV VERSION"
#AuthUserFile /home/sentineldev/public_html/.htpasswd
#Require valid-user
#ErrorDocument 401 "Unautorized Access"
Options +Indexes -MultiViews
RedirectMatch 403 ^/wp-includes/$
RedirectMatch 403 ^/wp-content/$

#------------------------------


RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
NRewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/resultant
RewriteRule !^resultant(/.*)?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]



#------------------------------



Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
# Turn on IE8-IE9 XSS prevention tools
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"


# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
   php_value post_max_size 3M
</IfModule>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/resultant [NC]
RewriteRule !^resultant(/.*)?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```

Comment: it give `The page isn't redirecting properly` when hit on https URL i need to rewrite all `https` URLS to `http` except the resultant page

Comment: I have checked it but now it is redirecting the  `resultant` page only to `home page` of the website wheras all other pages are redirecting smoothly from `https` to `http`

Comment: That means you have done other rules s well not shown in question. Try my updated rule in new browser.

Comment: now it is giving ` 500 Internal Server Error`. Please see my updated question i have pasted my whole `htaccess` file

Comment: There is a problem boy.. When Cron is hitting the URL it is not working and my order state remains in pending rather than processing. I dont know whats going wrong.. when I hit with https it is working fine now but not working with the callback URL payment gateway sends. pLease help

Comment: I have no idea about a cron mechanism in rewrite rule. You can test in browser or in Chrome dev tool to see this rule works fine.

Comment: Also I don't get this **my order state remains in pending rather than processing**. Are you noticing any `http://domain.com/resultant` URL in your server logs?